# Overriding all object inspectors in Unity

Tags: c#, unity

How can this be done? I want to add a single label to every component( including non-misbehavior ones ) in the inspector. I've tried:

```
[CustomEditor( typeof( Object ) )]
```

And:

```
[CustomEditor( typeof( Component ) )]
```

This seems to work for all components that don't seem to have a custom editor already( like BoxCollider, and Transform ). It seems if a component has a custom editor already, it ignores the one I've defined. Even if I change the attribute to this:

```
[CustomEditor( typeof( Transform ) )]
```

There is still no change to the Transform inspector. How can I define my own custom editor for these components?

Comment: Have you tried making a custom editor for MonoBehaviour?

Comment: Yes. It didn't work. Transform, rigid body and other "built in" types do not inherit from mono behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Using the CustomEditor attribute should certainly work for the Transform component.

I have my own custom editor for transforms to make resetting them a bit easier.

By creating the following CustomEditor you will notice that the localRotation changes from displaying three values that represent the Euler angles (x, y, z) of the rotation quaternion to the 4 values  (x, y, z, w) of the underlying rotation quaternion. This is because Unity is now using the CustomEditor which is empty and just shows the raw transform data structures.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Transform))]
public class TransformEditor : Editor 
{
}
```

To implement your own custom inspector make sure you override OnInspectorGUI() and place the relevant code there.

As you ahve said you will need to follow this approach for each component that already has a default Custom Inspector set up.